How can I retrieve a list of all devices connected to the Google Home App (such as Tuya, Philips, ZenSmart, etc.)?
After performing the ‘Account linking’ between my application and a Google Home App account, I want to list all devices from this Google Home App account. This includes devices originating from Nest (which I know is possible) or any other types of devices (such as Tuya, Philips, ZenSmart, etc.). Is there a way to do this? If so, is there an API or examples of how to create this on the backend?
I have conducted numerous searches, and the only thing I know that exists is an API for Google Nest. In my case, I want a listing of all types of devices in the Google Home App account

Google just recently unveiled the Google Home APIs at Google I/O, offering developers the capability to list all structures and devices linked to the Google Home ecosystem. With access to over 600 million devices through the new Device and Structure APIs, developers can seamlessly interact with various smart devices, including those from Nest, Matter-compatible light bulbs, and more.
For more in-depth insights, you can explore the details provided in the Google I/O presentation video. If you're eager to participate in the Google Home APIs Developer Program, you can sign up for the waitlist to stay updated on developments and opportunities in this space.
